# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'book_category'

Tags: python, html, django, database

**Hi? I'm new to web development can you plz help me whats the problem with my file?**

I don't know why is this, I have defined my category model properly and imported it. I have also defined book_category. Im stuck

**views.py:** the error is found here

```
class AddBookIndexView(View):
def get(self, request):
    booksQS = Books.objects.all()
    authorsQS = Author.objects.all()
    categoryQS = Category.objects.all()
    print(authorsQS)
    print(categoryQS)
    print(booksQS)
    return render(request, 'addbook.html')

def post(self, request):
    form = BooksForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        
        book_category = request.POST.get('book_category')
        
        firstname = request.POST.get('Firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('Lastname')
        author = Author.objects.filter(Q(firstname__icontains = firstname) & Q(lastname__icontains = lastname))
        if author:
            print(author)
        
        else:
            form = AuthorForm(firstname= firstname, lastname=lastname)
            form.save()
        
        
        category = Category.objects.filter(Q(book_category__icontains = book_category))
        if category:
            print(category)
        else:
            form = CategoryForm(book_category= book_category)#this is where the error
            form.save()

        author = Author.objects.filter(Q(firstname__icontains = firstname) & Q(lastname__icontains = lastname))
        
        category = Category.objects.filter(Q(book_category__icontains = book_category))
    
        for a in author:
            print(a.book_author_id)
            for c in category:
                print(c.book_category_no)
                book_title = request.POST.get('book_title')
                book_cover = request.FILES.get('book_cover')
                book_file = request.FILES.get('book_file')
                book_year = request.POST.get('book_year')
                book_tags = request.POST.get('book_tags')
                book_summary = request.POST.get('book_summary')
                
                form = Books(book_title = book_title, book_author_id = Author.objects.get(book_author_id = a.book_author_id), book_cover = book_cover,
                    book_file = book_file, book_year = book_year, book_summary = book_summary, book_category_no = Category.objects.get(book_category_no = c.book_category_no),
                    is_bookmarked = 0, is_downloaded = 0, is_read = 0, is_deleted = 0)

                
                form.save()
                return HttpResponse('Book Saved!')
        
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse('Not Valid')
```

**This is what my models.py looks like:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
class Category(models.Model):
# book_category_no = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
book_category_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
book_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Meta:
    db_table = "Category"

class Books(models.Model):
    # book_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    book_author_id = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    book_file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')
    book_year = models.DateField()
    book_tags = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    book_summary = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    book_category_no = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    # book_info = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default="")
    is_bookmarked = models.BooleanField()
    is_downloaded = models.BooleanField()
    is_read = models.BooleanField()

    is_deleted= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Books"
```

**Traceback**

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\ARMS\projectarms\arms\views.py" in post
315.              **form = CategoryForm(book_category= book_category)**

Exception Type: TypeError at /arms/addbook/
Exception Value: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'book_category'

`

Comment: You need to explain where `View` is defined or imported from.

Comment: What I meant was I have defined my Category model and CategoryForm properly

Comment: Please  add your models and full error trace

Comment: You haven't provided a stack  trace *(why not?)* and it's hard to suggest what might be wrong if we can't see the code that is raising the error.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here hahaha I have added the traceback above

Comment: The error appears in the CategroyForm. Please post your CategoryForm

Comment: this is my category form
`class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
   model = Category
   fields=('book_category',)
`

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The posted code does not get far enough to produce the error you claim.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly your Category or CategoryForm model is missing a field book_category which you use here:

```
category = Category.objects.filter(Q(book_category__icontains = book_category))
```

Comment: It has 

`class Category(models.Model):
 book_category_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 book_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

 class Meta:
  db_table = "Category" `